# Can someone tell me why there are two values for the dielectric constant from this website?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, refraction, metals, metamaterials

I have been looking up at available database that had dielectric constants for metals since I need them for my research and wanted to get an idea of what the values were before I focus on actually calculating them numerically if ever it is needed for my research. Thankfully I was able to find this website https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=Ti&page=Johnson However I noticed that there are two values for the relative permittivity when it came to metals and I was wondering why this is the case. From what I know so far, metals should have a negative permittivity, so I was confused as to why it shows that Titanium also has a positive permittivity. Can someone enlighten me as to why this is the case for the permittivities that I found on the website. Apologies as well for the question since I dont know a lot yet about the properties of materials when it comes to permittivity and permeability.[image]

Comment: When you square the measured complex refractive index, you get the real and imaginary parts of the relative permittivity.

Comment: I’m unclear about what you are unclear about here. You have $n$ and $k$ as a function of wavelength.

Comment: @JonCuster amateurAstro I  think he is asking about this: on the bottom right it reads $\epsilon_1=-9.75$ and $\epsilon_2=35.09$

Comment: Got it. Looks like @amateurAstro has it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative permeability (or dielectric constant) is a complex number, in this case given by $\epsilon = \epsilon_1 + i\epsilon_2$, related to n and k by: $\epsilon = (n+ik)^2$. Separating real and imaginary parts, it leads to: $\epsilon_1 = n^2 - k^2$, and $\epsilon_2 = 2nk$. You can check those numbers easily to see it matches the data given by the website.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful, I was not able to notice that beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index where the complex refractive index is defined as $\sqrt{\epsilon_1 + \mathfrak j \epsilon_2}=n+\mathfrak j k$. If you use the numbers on the bottom right with $\epsilon_1=-9.7538$ and $\epsilon_2=35.09$ then you get  $n=3.6515$ and $k=4.8049$, which is in the ballpark of the curves.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it was really helpful to me in understanding the problem.